# Task.Wait does not wait

Tags: .net, vb.net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

I am starting a new task in vb.net and wait for certain time. If by that time the task is not completed, I wan't to attach another task as continuation and inside that another task log elpased time of execution of task1. The code looks like that more or less:

```
Dim task As Task(Of Availability) = task.Factory.StartNew(
                                         Function() As Availability
                                             Return _GetAvailability(requests)
                                         End Function)
task.Wait(timeout)

If task.IsCompleted Then
    MyBase.availability = task.Result
Else
    task.ContinueWith(Sub(previous)
                         LogAvailabilityTimeout(timeout, elapsedTime)
                      End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
End If
```

For some reason occasionally the `task.Wait(timeout)` won't wait for that certain time and just skip right through. Since at that time there is no way the task is completed, so the LogAvailabilityTimeout task will be attached to it as continuation.
This results in a log like that:
*Task Timeoud! Timeout time: **10000ms**, Elapsed time: **3371ms***
I have exception logging in place etc and can confirm there are no exceptions and no errors. It just seems as the `task.Wait(timeout)` is randomly deciding not to wait...
Anyone came accross that before? Are there any solutions? Thanks for your time.

---- EDIT ----

Ok so I have done an experiment by adding a stopwatch and outputing stuff to debug:

```
Dim swTemp As StopWatch = StopWatch.StartNew()
Dim task As Task(Of Availability) = task.Factory.StartNew(
                                         Function() As Availability
                                             Return _GetAvailability(requests)
                                         End Function)
task.Wait(timeout)

swTemp.Stop()
Debug.WriteLine("Waited For: " & swTemp.ElapsedMilliseconds)

If task.IsCompleted Then
    MyBase.availability = task.Result
Else
    task.ContinueWith(Sub(previous)
                         LogAvailabilityTimeout(timeout, elapsedTime)
                      End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
End If
```

The `_GetAvailability` looks more or less like that:

```
Private Function _GetAvailability(requests As RequestsCollection) As Availability
    Dim swElapsed As New StopWatch = StopWatch.StartNew()
    'do some stuff here (CPU heavy and network related)
    swElapsed.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed: " & swElapsed.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    Me.elapsedTime = swElapsed.ElapsedMilliseconds
    Return xxx
End Function
```

It seems like it is indeed waiting for 10000, but there seems to be a big delay before inside of the `_GetAvailability` starts (*swElapsed* started).
So I have found out that `TaskFactory.StartNew()` does not always starts the task immediately, if the thread pool gets full the task will be put in the queue. While this is understandable, the `Task.Wait()` clearly does not take this into account, so the task might start after the wait has finished. I am reading now about TaskScheduler to check if I can increase thread pool to fit all the tasks, or do something else to solve the problem (but I have no idea what as for now hehe)... If you guys have any ideas let me know :)

---- EDIT ----

Another update for you ladies and gentelmen. The problem of thread pool filling up has been solved (initially) by hinting the new task creation with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`. This according to MS documentation hints the TaskScheduler that task might block thread pool for longer period, in which case the scheduler creates an extra thread to accomodate that. This is how I fire tasks now:

```
Dim task As Task(Of Availability) = task.Factory.StartNew(
                                         Function() As Availability
                                             Return _GetAvailability(requests)
                                         End Function, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
task.Wait(timeout)
```

Since this change all tasks seems to execute as they are being started (are not being put on the queue). This is in tests when I am firing around 50 tasks. I am now moving to more load testing (1000+ tasks).

Comment: Is `timeout` a constant or might it be updated? Also, how is `elapsedTime` computed?

Comment: timeout is a variable pulled from a config file (it is not updated anywhere in the code). elapsedTime is pulled from a stopwatch inside of the _GetAvailability() and assigned to a class variable

Comment: A class variable, you say. Is it possible that its value is overwritten by another task?

Comment: Sorry, not a class variable, an instance variable. Anyway, I have changed the timeout to a constant and hard-coded a value of 10000 and it is still doing that. I will check something else and report back by updating my code...

Comment: Your update is probably worth putting as an answer - you've correctly diagnosed that there's no guarantee that the task has even started by the time you call `Wait()`, and that the timeout you provide is the time that the current thread is willing to wait, not the amount of time that the task should be given.

Comment: If you have 50 long-running threads doing "heavy CPU and network related" activity, your program is going to spend a whole lot of time task switching. With 1,000+ tasks, it's likely that the computer will spend more time task switching than doing productive work--a condition known as "thrashing." You probably should find a way to limit your number of concurrent tasks to something more reasonable.

Comment: There is no way I can do it, it is part of "search engine", each search request from user fires about 50 searches for different service suppliers, results from all these searches are then being aggregated and displayed to a user. Provided there are on average 100 users searching, it will be ~5000. I probably would change how it is happening, but I am limited to maintanance and bug-fixing of an existing system...

Answer (score 1):

You could change your function as follows:

```
Private Function _GetAvailability(requests As RequestsCollection) As Tuple(Of Availability, Long)
    Dim swElapsed As New StopWatch = StopWatch.StartNew()
    'do some stuff here (CPU heavy and network related)
    swElapsed.Stop()
    Debug.WriteLine("Elapsed: " & swElapsed.ElapsedMilliseconds)
    Return Tuple.Create(xxx,swElapsed.ElapsedMilliseconds)
End Function
```

And then *always* attach your continuation method:

```
task.ContinueWith(Sub(previous)
    If previous.Item2 > timeout
         LogAvailabilityTimeout(timeout, previous.Item2)
    End If
End Sub, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion)
```

Which should at least sort out your reporting issue.